# How to set defaults values for a form in MEAN Stack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

New to MEAN stack and Angular 6. Developing a web application using MEAN Stack. Need to load default values to a `form` after clicking a `button`.

For that going to implement a `button` function. Need to access mongodb collection and get default values from the database.

How to access default values? Is it correct way, to follow the `List details by id` method in normal CRUD function. Is there any better way? Following this tutorial on [angular-5-crud-web-application-example](https://www.djamware.com/post/5a0673c880aca7739224ee21/mean-stack-angular-5-crud-web-application-example).

---UPDATED---

STEP 1: First I posted default data to the database.
I set username="default" for that data set.
STEP 2: Then I created a REST API to get that dataset by using userName

```
//Get single value by userName
router.get('/:userName', function(req, res, next) {
    extrudedHeightValue.findOne({'userName': req.params.userName}, function (err, post) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.json(post);
    });
  });
```

STEP 3: Then set a method for button click
Button in html

```
 <div class="form group">
       <input type="text" nbInput name="extrudedHeight" [(ngModel)]="extrudedHeight" />
  </div>

           <div class="">
              <button type='button' (click)="setDefaultValues(extrudedHeight)" class="btn btn-sm btn-rectangle btn-default text-case">Default Values</button>
           </div>
```

STEP 4:
Implemented the button click to get default values as follows.

In .ts file,

```
ngOnInit()
{
this.getDefaultValue(this.route.snapshot.params['userName']);
}

getDefaultValue(userName){
    this.http.get('/extrudedHeight/'+userName).subscribe(**data** => {this.extrudedHeightValue = data;});
  }

setDefaultValues(){
    this.getDefaultValue("default");
    //This method has not been completely implemented according to the requirement.
  }
```

But when I debug, bolded 'data' in 'getDefaultValue(userName)' method says error: unexpected end of input. When I searched for this error it says that this error comes due to not closing brackets etc. But I cannot identify what is it.
The other data says 'data is not defined'. So the values are not shown.

Comment: share some codes in your question, How you are planning to achieve the same?

Comment: That is the problem I have. I do not know how can I write the corresponding method. I added the tutorial that I am going to follow. But I have no clear idea of applying it into my scenario.

Comment: Let's break it down into three steps. Step 1, you'll create a REST API that lets you get the default values.  Step 2, you'll create a Reactive Form in Angular with a button which when clicked gets the default values. Step 3. You'll have to fetch the default values from that API, probably by using `HttpClients`'s `get` method. Once you receive those values, you can call `setValue` or `patchValue` methods on your form to set those default values to the form fields.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thanks for your suggestion. I will follow these steps.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I added the code following the way as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass query params directly like this

```
this.http.get('/defaultValues' + extrudedHeight)
```

It should be something like

```
this.http.get('/defaultValues?extrudedHeight=' + extrudedHeight)
```